# VBA: Set a row as range based on match value

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to define a range based on a match value in vba. This is my match function:

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Grand Total*", Range("A:A"), 0)
```

This will return the row that "Grand Total" is on, for example row 10.

Next i would need to set `srchrng` as that row, i.e. row 10.

How can this be done? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
Set srchrng = rows(Application.Match("Grand Total*", Range("A:A"), 0)).cells
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! This does the job alright. But now I have another problem. I want to limit this srchrng up till column CC. Is there any way to define it?

So it will result in a range of A10:CC10

Comment: @Tevin You could `Dim srchrng As Long` and then just get the row number from the `.Match` function. Then after that set the range like this `Set Finalrng = Range("A" & srchrng & ":CC" & srchrng)`. Maybe @Jeeped has a more elegant solution, but this should work :)